# Adding multiple div element by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create 4 `div` elements by clicking on button.
Please see, [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wQfLT/201/) for my current implementation.

In this current view the new element added to the bottom of each other.
My problem is that I don't know how to put them side by side.

I want to have 4 `div` elements (two at the top and two at the bottom, square shape)

Thats part of my code:

```
var box = document.getElementById('box'),
    template = box.getElementsByTagName('div'),


template = template[0];

submit1.onclick = function () {
    var new_field = template.cloneNode(true);
    box.appendChild(new_field);
    return false;
};
```

How can I do this?

Comment: your fiddle seems to be broken

Comment: FYI, you are cloning DIV with ID, making duplicate IDs which is not valid. You shouldn't set an ID on cloned DIV

Comment: CSS is handy here. You can either wrap each set of 2 `div`s inside another `div` acting as a row assigning a `display` property and/or `clear` property as required or you can use the `float` property if that suits. Either way a CSS solution would most likely be required.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `div's` default `display` is `block` so you need to add

```
display:inline-block;// add this to your div style
```

**Css**

```
div { margin:1em;display:inline-block; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wQfLT/204/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `float:left` as well as `display:inline-block` to your div.

```
div { margin:1em;float:left; }
```

OR

```
div { margin:1em;display:inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using CSS

```
div { float :left }
```

You can give dynamic id to each div so it doesnt effect to other div.

here's your demo

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6g2Gq/1/)